# Assigning a button to a userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am having trouble assigning a button to open my user form. I have tried for a while but cannot see where I have gone wrong. The user form is called userform1 and the button is called button. Any help would be appreacted.

```
Private Sub button_Click()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the trouble you're having?  We certainly can't see where you've gone wrong either...

Comment: it keeps saying method range of object_global failed... i dont understand the error

Comment: The error will actually be in the code in your `Userform_Initialize` or `Userform_Activate` events in all likelihood.

Comment: What Rory said. Put a Breakpoint on the `UserForm1.Show` line and step through (with [F8]) to see where the problem lies.